# Changing dot.profile and .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I need to change my dot.profile and .bashrc files in ubuntu 16.04 so that I can set up my android developer.  I can't save the files after I change them in an editor because they have root permissions but I can't change the permissions either. I need to set the 'JAVA_HOME' path in /etc/environment or ~/.bashrc configuration to the 'jdk1.8.0_45'.  Also I need to run /bin/bash --login everytime I run my terminal so that the path is set up right etc.

Can anyone help with these few minor problems?

Im not sure why I got downvoted...

Comment: you can use export JAVA_HOME="/your/path" in /etc/profile . I think is valid for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/etc/environment` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` are owned by root, as most files in that directory `/etc`. That is expected and should be so.

The files at `~/` a.k.a. `$HOME` which is usually `/home/username` should contain `.bashrc` and `.profile`:

```
$ ls ~/.bashrc ~/.profile
/home/user/.bashrc  /home/user/.profile
```

Those file should be own by the user, as is the usual in that directory.

If those files are own by root, change it. I Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo chown user:user ~/.bashrc ~/.profile
```

Please: use the correct user name !!

In any case, there should **not** be any `dot.profile` in any of both directories, and if it exist, you may confidently erase it.

Comment: `chown $USER` will assure that the right username is set. Group is not necessary to set at all, I think.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren It means no harm, it is a sensible change, and yes, it is necessary when a group of people needs access to a certain file.